# Why is "JAVA_HOME" path different from "which java" and "Whereis java"

Tags: java

In bash_profile the java_home is set as given below

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

command "echo $JAVA_HOME" gives the below path

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home

command "which java" gives the below path

/usr/bin/java

command Whereis java give the below path

/usr/bin/java

command "ls -la /usr/bin/java" gives the below link

lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 Jan 15  2019 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java

Why is that the java_home is different from the paths returned by "which java" and "Whereis java". Also why is /usr/bin/java linked to java in another location

Comment: It's probably because JAVA_HOME hasn't been set correctly during installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is that the java_home is different from the paths returned by "which java" and "Whereis java". Also why is /usr/bin/java linked to java in another location

JAVA_HOME is an environment variable

Any command run on shell / command prompt would be looked up in $PATH

by default "/usr/bin/*" is in PATH

To get your java and javac in PATH you will need to use following

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

This when put in your bashrc or bash_profile will always use java and its related executable binaries from your JAVA_HOME. Remember to put this before the existing path as shown above.

Hope this helps

Comment: "Remember to put this before the existing path as shown above" . this worked !! Thanks A G